# pytest skip portion of function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I have one function which does the some process and if fails then i am existing the code using `sys.exit(myfun())` but when i am testing using `pytest` i dont want to execute function `myfun()` inside sys.exit(). is there anyway in `pytest` it can be possible skip myfun()?

mypyfile.py

```
def process():
    # do some logic
    if failed:
       sys.exit(myfun()) # this i dont want to execute if i test via my pytest

def myfun():
    print("failed")
```

test_mypyfile.py

```
import pytest
import test_mypyfile
 
def test_process():
     test_mypyfile.process()
```

Comment: You can mock sys.exit, see exampel here: https://medium.com/python-pandemonium/testing-sys-exit-with-pytest-10c6e5f7726f

Answer (score 0):

You could mock `myfunc` in your test. This way the function is not called in the test process. I'll change a bit you're example so that it make more sense to mock (and you'll be able to see the difference):

```py
# mypyfile.py
from time import sleep

def process():
    # do some logic
    if failed:
       sys.exit(myfunc)

def myfun():
    sleep(4000)
```

```py
# test_mypyfile.py

import mock
import mypyfile
 
def test_process():
    
    mock.patch('mypyfile.myfunc')
    test_mypyfile.process()
```

Here `myfunc` will be called but you won't wait the 4000s.